# Python - calling several processes and sending input to them

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I wrote a twitter like service, and I want to do some stress testing on it with python.
I have a client program, called "client". 
I want to write a script that will start several processes of the the "client" program, send a few messages, wait a few seconds and will exit.

what I wrote is

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['client','c1','localhost','4981'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

now I can't call the communicate method, because it waits for an EOF but the process isn't over yet.
calling the stdin.flush doesn't seems to work either.

Any tips on how do I do this?
(I don't have to do this in python, if theres a way to do this with a bash script its also ok)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bash loop to run some clients and put them into the background. If you need to communicate with one, just put it to the foreground using *fg* and then put it to background again using *bg*

Comment: Do you mean in a shell script? can you please give me an example?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. This is small example. one script launch 5 copies of another, then try to kill. It's very simple but will show how to control process. Caller [link](http://ideone.com/1dpRm), client [link](http://ideone.com/gx0dk)

Answer (score 0):

Call `p.stdin.close()` to signal that there are no more messages:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# start several processes of the the "client" program
processes = [Popen(['client','c1','localhost','4981'], stdin=PIPE)
             for _ in range(5)]

# send a few messages
for p in processes:
    print >>p.stdin, message
    p.stdin.close()

# wait a few seconds (remove finished processes while we wait)
for _ in range(3):
    for p in processes[:]:
        if p.poll() is not None:
           processes.remove(p)
    time.sleep(1)

# and will exit (kill unfinished subprocesses)
for p in processes:
    if p.poll() is None:
       p.kill()
       p.wait()
```